# Send form data when clicking on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to post some form data when a user clicks on a table but I can
't get it to work. This is what I've tried so far:

```
<form Method="post">
  <table>
    <tr><th colspan="2">sometext</th></tr>
    <tr name="id" value="1"><td>Option 1</td><td>TEXT</td></tr>
    <tr name="id" value="2"><td>Option 2</td><td>TEXT</td></tr>
    <tr name="id" value="4"><td>Option 3</td><td>TEXT</td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I think I might need to use JavaScript but I don't know how to since I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: You can use jquery. Read [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery

```
jQuery('tr').click(function(){
     jQuery('form').submit();
});
```

But take a look at this article for further clearance :)
[Forms](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/tables.html)

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
<form Method="post" id="myForm">
<table id="mytable">
<tr><th colspan="2">sometext</th></tr>
<tr name="id" value="1"><td>Option 1</td><td>TEXT</td></tr>
<tr name="id" value="2"><td>Option 2</td><td>TEXT</td></tr>
<tr name="id" value="4"><td>Option 3</td><td>TEXT</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Few Changes to HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">

onload=function(){
document.getElementById("mytable").addEventListener('click',function(){
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
});
}

</script>
```